# How to add an array of dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
first_obj= [{"name":"sat","age":20}]
second_obj = [{"country":'India'}]
```

How to add array of dictionary in python?

```
third_obj = [{"name":'sat',"age":20,"country":'India'}]
```

Comment: why putting 1 element in your lists?

Answer (score 1):

```
first_obj= [{"name":"sat","age":20}]
second_obj = [{"country":'India'}]

third_obj = [{**first_obj[0], **second_obj[0]}]
print(third_obj)
```

**Output**

```
[{'name': 'sat', 'country': 'India', 'age': 20}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both objects will always have the same length, you can iterate both lists and merge the dictionaries:

```
third_obj = []
for a, b in zip(first_obj, second_obj):
   combined_dict = dict(a.items() + b.items()) # merge dictionaries
   third_obj.append(combined_dict)
```